# Like parameter in REST api url endpoint

Tags: rest, api, endpoint

Is it possible to pass parameters with 'like' keyword in REST api endpoints. Basically I'm trying to create an endpoint wherein I would query a db to get list of items based on '%name%'.
The corresponding query in DB would be like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id like "%arjun%"
```

So I would need to add parameters to my REST endpoint wherein i can fetch teh data based on name=%arjun%
Is that really possible?

Thanks
Arjun

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: I saw some examples of endpoints like : v1/endpoint/?query=key=value1&key2=value2.
But I couldn't find any examples of key like %value%

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to user `name=value` and then create your sql with %%. You can put % into your GET call but it can cause bugs because % is special character which is used to encode other special characters.

But if you really want to go with `name=%value%` then you can put %25 instead of %. So something like this `name=%25value%25`